# Cell Value Increment and Offset

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim storenum As Integer, cellval As Range, cellval1 As Range
cellval = Range("A6").Select
cellval1 = Range("A7").Select
Select Case cellval
    Case Is = Range("A6").Activate
    Range("A6").Value = 1

    End Select
Select Case cellval1
    Case Is = Range("A7").Activate
    Range("A7").Value = 2


End Select
```

When command button is clicked A6 will have the value 1 then move to A7 if button click again it will increment by 1 that will give 2.

EDIT: How to make value stay the same even one cell gets deleted. I think using with Static but I don't know how to put it in a right way I keep getting errors.

Comment: Ok. What's your question ?

Comment: So each time the button is clicked you want to add the value of A6 to A7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using *Public Variable* like this:

```
Public n As Long '~~> Declare a public variable at the top of the module
```

---

Then in your sub try something like this:

```
With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A6").Offset(n, 0) '~~> change to suit
    If n = 0 Then
        .Value =  1
    Else
        .Value =  .Parent.Range(.Address).Offset(-1, 0) + 1
    End If
    n = n + 1
End With
```

Comment: This works bro but What if I select one of cell then delete it then if I click the button again value should be the same as before.

Comment: @Anon231125 Ah that would be a different approach. Above code will continue to increment the cell being evaluated as you click.

Comment: Once I delete the last row cell value then click button it  reset to 1 then offset 1,0. How do I make something like that?

Comment: @Anon231125 Just the last row cell value? What if you deleted values in between? Would you mind posting another question and clearly specifying what you're trying to do and the attempts you made so far to get it? [See how to ask question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you won't attract down votes and attract more answers instead.

Comment: I have been searching a way if values deleted in between and it seems like its impossible. Now if just the last row cell value gets deleted , How can I continue increment value ?